Laravel + PHP FPM + MYSQL Issue: "Cannot assign address" while under heavy load
We have 3 digital ocean ubuntu droplets (*excluding the frontend which is nextjs):
BACKEND:
16 vcpus | 32GB ram
DB MYSQL:
8 vcpus | 16GB ram
REDIS:
4 vcpus | 32GB ram

We're runnign laravel -> through php-fpm -> behind nginx
We have the session and broadcasting drivers set to REDIS
We're using server ips to connect to both MYSQL & REDIS (no tls)

We're running a website that gets high concurrent users sporadically.
The load would jump from 0 to 90 in an instant, but it handles it just fine aside from the system config limitations that we get hit by every step of the way.
Over a week of debugging issues we did the following, solving a bottleneck and jumping to the next:

We started utilizing opcache
We've set php-fpm in static mode with max connections set to 2000 so we have 2000 fpm processes running waiting to handle requests (process restart after fulfilling 1000 requests)
We faced an issue with NGINX worker connections where they were low and would drop requests, so we've increased that to 7500
We then faced an issue with the nofile limit and we've set that to 50_000
We've hit MYSQL's MAX_CONNECTIONS and we've increased that from 151 to 2000

After all of this everything seemed to be ticking fine. Although we started having another issue related to the max allowed open tcp connections per port, which the server uses to connect to MYSQL & REDIS

This issue would render the following error: "Cannot assign requested address"

We've run a simple stress test by hitting a single endpoint that reads from both mysql and redis
1000 concurrent request sent 50 times for a total of 50k consecutive requests
Around the 35k requests mark, the requests would start failing with the above error. Upon further inspection and running netstat -anlp | grep :3306 | grep TIME_WAIT -wc while doing the stress test, we noticed the number grows up and up as the requests come in, it would quickly reach 35k at which point that error starts to occur. These TIME_WAIT connections seems to be closing after 60 seconds. Upon research we tried lowering that number to 3 seconds with net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 3 & sysctl -p but to no avail :/ The connections remain open for 60 seconds always and it's causing a big bottleneck under heavy load.
What should we do?
PS: RAM AND CPU were performing just fine under the simple stress test.
EDIT: Using persistent connections for both mysql and redis has solved the issue, + our CPU usage has dropped drastically on both the backend droplet and mysql.

Talking from Redis usage perspective, less grasp on the others:
What is the gain with using many connections to the same server?
You can have some pool depends on the implementation of the client you use, but creating a connection per request is useless.
You should understand the limitations, use the maximum amount of connection Redis server can efficiently handle, and re-use the same connections.
You should also understand the architecture of the client you use, if it is a multiplexer for example, even more than one connection is useless.
Having more and more connections sending more requests of what Redis (or MYSQL for that matter) can serve is just misusing of resources, its using a private car for each request and sitting in traffic instead of all moving to public transportation, its not faster, and you need much much more resources.
If you need more TPS you should scale up Redis, move to cluster mode and add more replications so you can read from more endpoints and the traffic has "load balancing" between shards, the amount of connections should be almost constant compare to the amount of nodes the cluster has.
With the proper usage Redis will be much faster than the requests getting in (Valkey, the OSS fork of Redis, just announced Valkey 8 with 1million TPS, that's more than most apps need, and its not require connection per request).
I guess the same is even more true for MySQL, the amount of connection should be determined by the ability of the DB to serve requests and a small margin, there's no logic holding more.

Can't really use a connection pool here because the 1 process per request model, and don't have much to create a pool in front of a proxy. I've shied away from using persistent connections, especially with mysql since a lot of people online advice against it. I believe laravel does some good transaction cleanup at the end of each request so it will probably be fine. Will test it out and see if it causes any trouble. This seems better than hackily having to tinker with tcp timeouts.. Thank you will see how it goes.

As said, not sure about the other but Redis, but I'm doing it for my job, Elasticache and ValKey-Glide core contributor (it's also part of my job). I'm working with huge costumers daily with very high performance needs, and I'm constantly dealing with creating the best client's config for maximizing performance.  It's not advised at all to hold more connection than what effective. Keep an eye, PHP client is planned for the next phases.

I gotchu no worries :) what did you mean by "PHP client is planned for the next phases."? im out of the loop

The link is to a multilingual client library, currently supporting binding for Java, node and python and Go is under development. Next in line are C# and PHP.
